# Open launch files with gedit using HTML default

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I open a file with extension `.launch` using the gedit, the file open without Plain Text. After I choose the option `HTML` in Plain Text Menu, I closed the file and openned again, the file start with `HTML` format.
My question is: Is there a way to make default `HTML` for the entire `.launch` extension?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273112/open-launch-files-with-gedit-using-html-default/) by [Thadeu Brito](https://answers.ros.org/users/29268/thadeu-brito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more a Linux/platform configuration issue than a ROS issue. Could you please post this sort of question on a more appropriate forum in the future?

I'm not sure it's the best way (or even the recommended way), but it would appear that configuring a default highlighter for specific file types is possible using a 'language definition file'.

See [an I set a default syntax highlighting in Gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/a/310553) on Ask Ubuntu.

> After I choose the option `HTML` in Plain Text Menu

Know that `.launch` files are XML, not HTML. If Gedit has a highlighter for that, I would use the XML highlighter.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thadeu Brito](https://answers.ros.org/users/29268/thadeu-brito/) on 2017-10-17**:
Thank you! I understand about that post being a question of other platform. When I did this post, I thought someone users ROS known about it. In the future, I dont will  this mistake!.